# ORACLE Join tables on a single field and account for minor difference (specific example provided)

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to join two tables on a field (FILE_NAME); however, there are a couple records in just one of the table, in which a timestamp is appended to the end of the file name and before the file extension.  I'm not sure how to account for these.  I found an Oracle function,
 REGEXP SUBSTR (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions131.htm), that seems like it may give me what I need, but I have to admit that this is extremely advanced to me and am not sure how to apply it.

My sample tables are:

FILE_INFO Table:

```
FILE_NAME | FILE_ID
REGIONS_ACCOUNTED.xlsx | 21
TSM_INSAT.xml | 14
```

FILE_PARAMETERS Table:

```
FILE_NAME
TSM_INSAT.xml
REGIONS_ACCOUNTED-08112017.xlsx
```

From what I can tell, it seems that the timestamps are always prefixed with a dash (-) so I originally thought to approach it by finding the index of a dash then use substr to concat the before and afters of the timestamp but can't figure out how to do that in a query or how to account for date ranges (e.g.:

```
REGIONS_ACCOUNTED-07102017-07142017.xlsx
```

At this point, I just have a basic Join:

```
SELECT a.file_name, b.file_location 
FROM reports.file_info a
LEFT OUTER JOIN reports.file_parameters b on (a.file_name = b.file_name);
```

The SQL above of course excludes those reports with dates/date ranges in the filename.  It would be better to use a file_id, I'm sure; however, there is no file_id in the file_parameters.
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try using `REGEXP_REPLACE(b.file_name,'\-\d+\.','.')`. This pattern looks for the pattern "hyphen followed by one of more numbers followed by a period" and then replaces the whole chunk with just a period.

Comment: @HepC, thanks!  That works for most records; however, there are a few outliers, for example: TMS_PLANNED_NO_MCPC_ASSOCIATED-en_2011-04-26T181912802z.xlsx   <---I'm not sure what that means; however, the corresponding match in the other table is: TMS_PLANNED_NO_MCPC_ASSOCIATED.xlsx.  So I changed the function to this:  REGEXP_REPLACE(a.file_name,'\-[\d\w\-\ _]+.,'.') and it is still not capturing/replacing the affected record.  I used that sample on https://regex101.com/ and my regex string is the same: \-[\d\w\-\ _]+. and it works on that website.  Do you know why this wouldn't be working?

Comment: It's because the regex is looking for numbers and that example starts with letters. You could try this one instead. `REGEXP_REPLACE(b.file_name,'\-.*\.','.')`. It replaces 'hyphen, maybe some characters then a period'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Hepc provided the correct answer (in the comments).  The modified version to account for date ranges is:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(a.file_name,'\-[\d\w\-\_]+.,'.')
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for match of filenames from FILE_INFO in FILE_PARAMETERS.

```
SELECT a.file_name, 
       b.file_location 
  FROM reports.file_info a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN reports.file_parameters b 
    ON b.file_name LIKE CONCAT('%', SUBSTR(a.file_name, 1, INSTR(a.file_name,'.',-1)-1), '%', SUBSTR(a.file_name, INSTR(a.file_name,'.',-1), LENGTH(a.file_name)), '%');
```